# Getting next index after allocate max value index using Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, max

I have the following array which consists of 10 values:

```
values = [5,4,15,2,7,1,0,25,9,6]
```

And I want to find the maximum value as index and subtract the next index from it, so the output should be the range between the two indices, I tried to do the below code:

```
start= 0
step=2
length=10

while start <= length:
   max_val = np.max(values)
   idx = np.where(values == max_val)
   print('max', max_val)
   print('max index', np.where(values == max_val))
   idx_all= values[i]
   
   print(max_val)
   range1= values[idx[0]] - values[idx[0]+1];
   print('range', range1)

   start=start+step
```

The maximum value and its index are correct, However, I get the following output error at finding the difference between the two indices:

```
max 25
max index (array([7], dtype=int64),)
25

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-de731383e093> in <module>
     15 
     16     print(max_val)
---> 17     range1= values[idx[0]] - values[idx[0]+1];
     18     print('range', range1)
     19 

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

I was wondering how can I edit this to make the output know the next index and subtract it?
Thank you.

Comment: before while loops do `values = np.array(values)`.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Ok :-). I also tried, even with large array, max at end, and shuffling, [max+index was faster](https://tio.run/##dZFNbsIwEIX3PsVsUBw0QoQU@iNxgi56gKqK0mYMVmPHchwEp08ncSCw6Mr2PL9vxs/uEo6NzV@c73vlGwNBG9IBtHGND9NJjErjyJeh8VdNBzIHCoF81H1pK14mtT12StUkREUKPuqTtjJ9EwDaVnRGOJV1R7AHU54l2c4MaJJjtU0Rfumyn/kyS1O2egqdtw@EiH@nur5E/D13ol2bcjVWVuMxyv9yVWd/WraMo2NsIUQEcPlzi0@YbXGDz5jhGjdbfMXdl1Ccj2IUjP5hIue1DVJJfoKw7MzWy@VuBtW6DZKjO5C0fGXwt4M/6ewUYZUgJLf9jExvu/GNj51hCflwFSBwk/iNUiFw1N/k91k6atGeLPIKTAsJLEAGdmaU8x@oVVHY0lBRDJenAe5CncIsnSNb8fB9/wc).

Comment: @KellyBundy, interpreted languages are full of joy, you never know :D

Comment: @OlvinRoght Python being interpreted seems like a red herring here, as both of our solutions have very little Python interpreted. All the hard work is done solely in Python's C code.

Comment: @KellyBundy, that's about implementations. You can patch any algorithm which search max value to return also an index and it will be faster option then iterate over array twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this code should accomplish what you're looking for:

```
values = [5,4,15,2,7,1,0,25,9,6]
max_val = np.max(values)
idx = list(np.where(values == max_val)[0])[0]
max_val = values[idx]
value = max_val - values[idx+1]
print(value)
```

This will output 16 for this example.

Answer (score 0):

This outputs 16, which is true because 9 is next to 25

```
values = [5,4,15,2,7,1,0,25,9,6]
# get the maximum value first
mm = max(values)
index = 0
next_index = 0
# iterate through the array while checking for the max index
for i in range(0, len(values)):
    if(values[i]==mm):# this is the index of the maximum element
        index = i
        next_index = i+1 # break out of the loop
        break

# get the element at next index
el = values[next_index]
# get the difference with the maximum
diff = mm - el
print(diff)
```